# Tabpanel. Long tab title overlaps close tool

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a tabpanel with with `maxTabWidth` property set to `200`. The problem is, when there are tabs with text beyond those 200px, then they start looking ugly. The worst thing is that such text overlaps close tool (small button which closes the tab). Probably, there is some property that can solve this style issue.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't happen with the default styles and CSS; the text area in the tab has `overflow: hidden` set, so it truncates the text.

I would first look at what your CSS is doing that is preventing this.

Comment: The catch is - I do not use any custom CSS

Comment: Maybe you haven't loaded the ExtJS provided ones properly? Or haven't rebuilt since adding tabs - remember, ExtJS only includes CSS for components that you use.

Have you checked out if you have the `overflow:hidden` set on the tab using something like the Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug?